# write script without CDATA and Merge two scripts with same functions

Tags: javascript

I have these scripts which are almost the same but I'm unable to merge them into one..
also I want remove "CDATA" and keep the script functioning in blogger XML template

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA[
!function(){const e=document.querySelectorAll(".vplayer");for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++){console.log(e[t].dataset.v);const a="//i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/"+e[t].dataset.v+"/hqdefault.webp";var n=new Image;n.src=a,n.addEventListener("load",void e[t].appendChild(n)),e[t].addEventListener("click",function(){const e=document.createElement("iframe");e.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",""),e.setAttribute("frameborder","0"),e.setAttribute("src","//www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.dataset.v+"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&noCookie=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xotaku.com&widgetid=1"),this.innerHTML="",this.appendChild(e)})}}();// ]]></script>
```

and that the second

```
    <script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA[
!function(){const e=document.querySelectorAll(".vplayerold");for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++){console.log(e[t].dataset.v);const a="//i.ytimg.com/vi/"+e[t].dataset.v+"/hqdefault.jpg";var n=new Image;n.src=a,n.addEventListener("load",void e[t].appendChild(n)),e[t].addEventListener("click",function(){const e=document.createElement("iframe");e.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",""),e.setAttribute("frameborder","0"),e.setAttribute("src","//www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.dataset.v+"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&noCookie=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xotaku.com&widgetid=1"),this.innerHTML="",this.appendChild(e)})}}();// ]]></script>
```

the scripts are the same and I dont want write the whole of it twice
I want this

```
const e = document.querySelectorAll(".vplayer");
```

to work with that

```
const a = "//i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/" + e[t].dataset.v + "/hqdefault.webp";
```

and this

```
const e = document.querySelectorAll(".vplayerold");
```

to work with that

```
const a="//i.ytimg.com/vi/"+e[t].dataset.v+"/hqdefault.jpg";
```

the rest of scripte work with both as well

Comment: The CDATA thing has not been necessary for almost 2 decades.

Comment: @Pointy — If removing it causes a problem then maybe they are using XHTML (e.g. in a Blogger template… I've no idea if Blogger still uses its nightmare XML templates or not though).

Comment: Please read [ask]. Provide a [mcve]. Do some [debugging](https://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/). Don't just tell us it [doesn't work](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: Please show us how you tried to "*murge them into one*". Also they look very similar, suggesting that you should rewrite them anyway using a shared function that you can call twice.

Comment: @Quentin yes yes you are right its on blogger XML and it stop working without it ):

Comment: @Pointy but its necessary in blogger XML templates

Comment: @Bergi I added more explanations to my post.. thank you for the informations

Comment: oh wow, well I have sympathy for anybody dealing with XML in 2021 (edit: I have to deal with it too for some Flying Saucer PDF files :( )

Comment: @RyυĸKυяαɪ Thanks for the clarification. At first it sounded like you had problems to "*keep the script functioning*" if you simply threw both codes in one script tag.

Comment: @Pointy well I have many reasons ..

Comment: @Bergi no it dont work it give an error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list .. and I dont want call the whole code twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want remove "CDATA" and keep the script functioning in blogger XML template

That's not possible. It's pretty much required for valid XML unless you want to use escape sequences for `<>'"`.

> the scripts are the same and I dont want write the whole of it twice

Make that IEFE a named function declaration, give it parameters, call it twice with different arguments.

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
function createPlayer(selector, makeUrl) {
    const e = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var t = 0; t < e.length; t++) {
        console.log(e[t].dataset.v);
        const a = makeUrl(e[t].dataset.v);
        var n = new Image;
        n.src = a;
        n.addEventListener("load", void e[t].appendChild(n));
        e[t].addEventListener("click", function() {
            const e = document.createElement("iframe");
            e.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "");
            e.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
            e.setAttribute("src", "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.dataset.v + "?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&noCookie=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xotaku.com&widgetid=1");
            this.innerHTML = "";
            this.appendChild(e);
        })
    }
}
createPlayer(".vplayer", v => "//i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/" + v + "/hqdefault.webp");
createPlayer(".vplayerold", v => "//i.ytimg.com/vi/" + v + "/hqdefault.jpg");
//]]></script>
```

Comment: thank you dude that exactly what I need, but there is error Unexpected token '<'

Comment: and you also answered my questions.. thank you so much, just.. should I use type="text/javascript" or its defaut anyway ? in XML

Comment: @RyυĸKυяαɪ i thought whatever platform you are using would strip out the `CDATA` before passing the result to a browser, or it would pass them as XHTML to a browser that is actually XML-capable - if not, you need to comment them out so that it's still valid HTML as well.

Comment: @RyυĸKυяαɪ Regarding `type="text/javascript"`, that's pretty much optional since HTML5

Answer (score 0):

## Merged example

You mean like this?

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>// <![CDATA[
!function(){const e=document.querySelectorAll(".vplayer");for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++){console.log(e[t].dataset.v);const a="//i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/"+e[t].dataset.v+"/hqdefault.webp";var n=new Image;n.src=a,n.addEventListener("load",void e[t].appendChild(n)),e[t].addEventListener("click",function(){const e=document.createElement("iframe");e.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",""),e.setAttribute("frameborder","0"),e.setAttribute("src","//www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.dataset.v+"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1&iv_load_policy=3&modestbranding=1&noCookie=false&origin=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xotaku.com&widgetid=1"),this.innerHTML="",this.appendChild(e)})}}();

!function(){const e=document.querySelectorAll(".vplayerold");for(var t=0;t<e.length;t++){console.log(e[t].dataset.v);const a="//i.ytimg.com/vi/"+e[t].dataset.v+"/hqdefault.jpg";var n=new Image;n.src=a,n.addEventListener("load",void e[t].appendChild(n)),e[t].addEventListener("click",function(){const e=document.createElement("iframe");e.setAttribute("allowfullscreen",""),e.setAttribute("frameborder","0"),e.setAttribute("src","//www.youtube.com/embed/"+this.dataset.v+"?rel=0&showinfo=0&autoplay=1"),this.innerHTML="",this.appendChild(e)})}}();
// ]]>
</script>
```

Adding them in separate script tags should also work, depending what your backend allows you to do.

Comment: "This will ignore the rest of the line and therefore interpret `</script>` to be a javascript comment." — No, it won't. The XML or HTML parser will parse the script element, extract the content, then pass the contents to the JS compiler.

Comment: "(For HTML5)" — The OP has already clarified in the comments that they are writing a Blogger template, not an HTML 5 document.

Comment: @RyυĸKυяαɪ Use the `@` symbol when replying to someone other than the author of the post you're commenting on, like I did at the start of this comment.

Comment: I dont want write the whole scripts twice.. i edited my post with more explanation.. thank you for your help

Comment: @HereticMonkey ok thank you so much I willl use it

Comment: @Quentin thank you for Your clarifications, so in blogger template I have to use type="text/javascript", and its not the default ?

Comment: I've no idea. I just know that when I last looked at Blogger (a long time ago) it used XML so CDATA was significant.